# The annihilator of an intersection

Tags: linear-algebra

I know this question has been arlready asked, but as my reputation is too low I'm not allowed to post a comment, sorry for this second post.

I'm asked to prove :

1. $(W_1+W_2)^0=W_1^0\cap W_2^0$.
2. $(W_1\cap W_2)^0=W_1^0+W_2^0$

I managed to prove the first equation, but only "half" of the second one, i.e. to prove that $W_1^0+W_2^0$ is included in $(W_1\cap W_2)^0$.

I'm really stuck here, I don't know how to prove the reverse inclusion. I tried to use the dimension formula but it didn't lead me to anything satisfying.

Did I make a mistake? Or can anyone give me a hint here?

Thanks

Answer (score 10):

As pointed out [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/428225/8271), the relations
\begin{gather*}
(W_1 + W_2)^0 = W_1^0 \cap W_2^0 \tag{1}\\
(W_1 \cap W_2)^0 \supseteq W_1^0 + W_2^0\tag{2}
\end{gather*}
are valid for arbitrary vector spaces.

It's easy to check that $W_1^0 + W_2^0$ is a subspace of $(W_1 \cap W_2)^0$. If $W_1$ and $W_2$ are subspaces of a finite dimensional vector space $V$ then we have
\begin{align*}
\dim (W_1^0 + W_2^0) &= \dim W_1^0 + \dim W_2^0 - \dim(W_1^0 \cap W_2^0)\\
&= \dim V - \dim W_1 + \dim V - \dim W_2 - \dim (W_1 + W_2)^0 \\
&= 2\dim V - \dim W_1 - \dim W_2 - \left[\dim V -\dim(W_1 + W_2)\right] \\
&= \dim V - \dim W_1 - \dim W_2 + \dim W_1 + \dim W_2 - \dim (W_1\cap W_2)\\
&= \dim V - \dim (W_1\cap W_2)\\
&= \dim (W_1\cap W_2)^0.
\end{align*}
So $W_1^0 + W_2^0$ is a subspace of $(W_1 \cap W_2)^0$ with $\dim(W_1^0 + W_2^0) = \dim (W_1 \cap W_2)^0$, therefore 
$$W_1^0 + W_2^0 = (W_1 \cap W_2)^0.$$

Comment: Nice answer. How do you proof equation number 2 (one of the two that apply to arbitrary vector spaces)?

Comment: Get an element on the set on the left. Use the definitions of sum of vector spaces, annihilator space, and belonging to the annihilator of the intersection.