# Prove $U^0+W^0 = (U \cap W)^0$ for subspaces $U,W$ of $V$

Tags: linear-algebra, dual-spaces

I can prove that $U^0+W^0 \subset (U \cap W)^0$, however the other side I find very difficult to prove.

Surely I could take some linear functional $\phi \in (U \cap W)^0$, where $\phi(v) = 0 \space\forall v \in U \cap W$. This does not necessarily mean that $\phi(u) = 0 \space \forall u \in U!$

Am I thinking right?

Note: $X^0$ is the annihilator of $X$

Comment: If $\phi\in(U\cap V)^0$, then $\phi\in U^0$ is not true in general. However, This question does not ask you to prove $\phi\in U^0$ or $\phi\in V^0$, it says $\phi\in U^0+V^0$. This assertion means there are $\psi\in U^0$ and $\eta\in V^0$ such that $\phi=\psi+\eta$.

Comment: Check this question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/347480/the-annihilator-of-an-intersection-is-the-sum-of-annihilators

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3827386/annihilator-in-infinite-dimensional-vector-space